# L'adverbe « idiomatiquement ». Existe-t-il ou non ? Quand peut-on « adverbialiser » un adjectif en lui ajoutant -ment ?

Tags: usage, adverbes, dictionnaires

Mon correcteur de texte ne reconnaît pas « idiomatiquement ».

J'ai consulté plusieurs dictionnaires en ligne. Bizarrement, certains en parlent d'autres pas.

Parmi ceux qui en parle on retrouve

[Reverso](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/idiomatiquement) et [wiki](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/idiomatiquement)

En revanche

[larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/rechercher?q=idiomatiquement&l=francais&culture=) et [la 9e édition (1992-...) du Dictionnaire de l'Académie française](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/idiomatiquement?page=1)

n'en parle pas. Pourquoi cette incohérence ?

Ayant vu le diagramme pertinent de [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=idiomatiquement&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cidiomatiquement%3B%2Cc0) je n'arrive pas à déduire si le mot est acceptable ou pas.

Quelles règles dictes si un adjectif donne lieu à un adverb en -ment ou faut-il utiliser de manière, de façon, etc. ? (P.ex. ici de façon idiomatique)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Quelles règles dictent si un adjectif donne lieu à un adverbe ?

Étant dit que tout adjectif est susceptible de former un adverbe, ce qui fait de cette catégorie la ressource la plus féconde en néologismes.

On observe cependant, en français, que certains adjectifs offrent des **résistances** à l'adverbialisation.

Bertrand (1986) observe que, c'est le cas, sauf par métaphore, pour les adjectifs désignant une qualité perceptible par les sens (*proche-ment* ne se dit pas).
Pareil pour les adjectifs désignant une espèce (*canin-ement* ne se dit pas).

Avec lui, de nombreux linguistes concluent que **les adjectifs désignant un état ne sont pas candidats à l'adverbialisation**.
Pour être adverbialisé, l'adjectif doit, au contraire, *"pouvoir intégrer le plan temporel dans lequel se déroulent les procès"*. (Moignet). Il s'agit d'une contrainte sémantique forte.

L'adjectif ne doit pas désigner un état, *idiomatique* (à mon sens) désigne un état => Pas candidat à l'adverbialisation.

J'insiste sur le fait qu'il s'agit d'un point de vue, d'un regard sur la langue. D'une **description**. L'adjectif désignant un état n'est pas usuellement adverbialis**é**. Il semble **résister** à l'adverbialisation.

Partant de cette observation, il existe nécessairement des grammairiens prescriptivistes pour juger qu'un tel adjectif ne **doit pas** servir de base à la construction d'un adverbe et ainsi l'exclure de leurs lexiques ! <sup>1</sup>

<sub>1. On notera que je n'ai pas écrit *être adverbialisé*... je crois avoir compris que le verbe *adverbialiser* pose quelques problèmes à ces gens-là... alors... je fais gaffe... ;-)</sub>

EDIT : Sur le propos de l'adverbialisation on peut observer pas mal de trucs bien curieux qu'aujourd'hui encore on ne s'explique pas bien comme par exemple le fait que nombre d'adjectifs en *-able* ne sont pas adverbialisés alors que leurs antonymes le sont usuellement (*réparable-ment* non mais *irréparable-ment* si...)

Comment: J'ai inclut "adverbialisé" au titre de la question:-)! J'aime beaucoup ce mot ! Merci pour ta réponse.

Comment: @dimitris : vu! et... lol! Hè! Entre guillemets... c'est pas du jeu ça!... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Je crois que l'on dois cela tout simplement au degré d'utilité que le « mot » a eu dans la culture particulière où on croit devoir le trouver et qui est donc quasiment nul pour « idiomatiquement ». Ce degré d'utilité d'un mot peut être nul soit parce que sans un besoin fréquent pour le concept donné les utilisateurs du langage utilisent à sa place une périphrase, soit parce que le besoin du concept a toujours été nul, soit parce qu'il n'a pas été totalement nul mais qu'il n'y a pas eu de stimulation assez forte chaque fois que la nécessité d'un mot s'est faite sentir pour que le mot soit défini. Le terme peut avoir été défini une fois et avoir eu l'avantage d'une parution, mais cela n'est pas suffisant pour les lexicographes (lexicographes français tout au moins) dans leur processus de décision pour placer un mot dans les listes; c'est le cas pour le mot « idiomaticité » que le TLFi cite mais ne liste pas dans les entrées.
La seule règle semble être la fréquence de l'emploi ou plutôt l'importance de la réutilisation dans des parutions en une période initiale de la naissance du concept et du mot. On trouve par exemple que dans la langue anglaise il existe une tendance pour associer automatiquement l'adverbe à l'adjectif, même si cet adverbe aura en fin de compte une utilisation restreinte. C'est une des différences entre les méthodologies linguistiques du français et de l'anglais.